# Unexpected PHP/jQuery/JSON interaction differences

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, python, json

### Background:

So, I have the following PHP snippet written to help me debug a much larger problem, but now I'm even more confused as to how jQuery and PHP expect JSON to be sent/received, as this code does not seem to be doing what I expect:

I want to be able to *receive* data as either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` ***or*** as `application/json`, while responding only with `application/json` (for now).

**`test.php`:**

```
<?php

$content_type = $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'];

switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    case 'GET':
        echo <<< _EOF
<html>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
_EOF;
        break;
    case 'POST':
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        if ($content_type == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded') {

            $_POST['message'] = 'debugged';
            echo json_encode($_POST);

        # Otherwise, get raw body data.
        } else {
            $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
            if ($data == null) {
                $data = file_get_contents('php://stdin');
            }

            $object = json_decode($data, true);
            $object['message'] = 'debugged';

            echo json_encode($object);
        }
        break;
    default:
        echo "These aren't the droids you're looking for. Move along.<br />";
        break;
}
```

### Testing:

I've been testing this code using both the [Python Requests Library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) and [jQuery's Ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

In Python, data can be sent as either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or as raw body data attached to the request, depending on the type of the `data` argument you supply to the `post()` method (see [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) for more information).

### All going well so far...

Using Requests, I get exactly what I expect.

When the `data` parameter of the `post()` method is a **Python dictionary object,** the data is sent form-encoded:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.post('http://example.com/test.php', data={"name": "tester", "message": "bug"})
>>> print r.text
{"message": "debugged", "name": "tester"}
```

When the `data` parameter is a **literal string (note the single-quotes!)** the data is sent as the body of the request, and may (or may not) be interpreted as JSON at the endpoint (I do interpret it as JSON in the sample PHP code above, and it's guaranteed it will only ever be JSON):

```
>>> r = requests.post('http://example.com/test.php', data='{"name": "tester", "message": "bug"}')
>>> print r.text
{"message": "debugged", "name": "tester"}
```

Both of these results are what I expect.

### Here's the weird part...

I seem to be getting different responses from this code, not depending on ***how*** I send the data, but ***what I use to send it*** (i.e. Requests, or jQuery). There must be something different between the two that I'm completely missing.

If I point my browser (Chrome) at http://example.com/test.php, triggering the GET request handler to serve me the tiny HTML page contained in the PHP code above, and then fire the following jQuery code in the JavaScript console, this is what I get back as a result:

```
> var output = null;
> $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://example.com/test.php',
      data: {
          name: 'tester',
          message: 'bug'
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function(x) {
          if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
              x.overrideMimeType('application/json; charset=UTF-8');
          }
      },
      success: function(d) {
          $output = d;
      }
  });
> output
Object {message: "debugged"}
```

By now I'm thinking, ***where the heck did the 'name' entry go?***

As it turns out, only the things that I ***explicitly set*** from within the PHP handler seem to be accessible as output to jQuery. But sometimes I want to use data from a user's input, modify it, and then return it as output. But with jQuery acting like this, (or PHP... I'm not exactly sure in which bit of code my error lies) I'm unable to do what I want.

### Weirder still!

The next thing I did was to change the output message to be "debugged (form-data)" or "debugged (body-data)" depending on whether the if-statement in the POST handler was entered or "elsed", and was surprised to find that **jQuery is sending the data as body data, but is setting the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header.** This is completely not what I expected. I feel like either one of jQuery (1.10.2) or Python Requests is misbehaving due to this discrepancy, but I'm not sure which. (Or is sending form-encoded data really this ad-hoc?)

Any thoughts or insight on what's going on here, what I'm missing, what I SHOULD be expecting if my expectations or wrong, or even links to relevant documentation I've managed to overlook while researching this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should make sure you use the Chrome developer tools so that you can look at the raw HTTP headers that the browser is actually sending to (and receiving from) the server.

Comment: It's sorta interesting for testing purposes, but it's a strange way of both sending and handling requests, and it seems overly complicated, and I have a strange feeling that the the "name" entry doesn't really dissapear, but something you did made it dissapear a long the way passing thru all the strangeness.

Comment: As far as i know when you pass an object to `data` its going to be encoded like a form-urlencoded because its run through `jQuery.param`. Try using string as `data` that is pre-encoded with `JSON.stringify`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the identifier "name" in quotes. It's a reserved word and some parsers don't handle it not being in quotes well. I ran into a similar problem a couple of years back.